# nestedscroolview doesn't scroll well inside another nestedscrollview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-nestedscrollview

I have a bottom sheet dialog with 2 `nestedscrollview`, the outer one wrap the entire view, the inner one wrap a single `textview`, I have 2 problems:

***1.***
the the inner one can scroll only down, as you can see in the gif:

[image]

I need to make the inner `nestedscrollview` scrollable in both direction and the outer `nestedscrollview` scrollable when I drag outside the inner one, how can I do it?

***2.***
I need to make the inner `nestedscrollview` to wrap text, tried with constraints but not working, wrap_content make the entire `textview` to be shown, making the `scrollview` a simple `textview`.

How can I do it?

This is my XML code:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/outer_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ViewSwitcher
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/inner_scrollview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="200dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

        </ViewSwitcher>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: To make nested scrolling work on the Lollipop and above versions, you have to enable it for a child scroll view by adding android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" to its XML declaration or by explicitly calling setNestedScrollingEnabled(true). So on TextView set enable this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Some R&D at my End I have Finalised the XML Layout, Its Working For Me.

Actually the issue was the Wrong layout Designing. Grab the Latest Changes from Below.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/outer_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ViewSwitcher
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/inner_scrollview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="200dp"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
                
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="25dp"></TextView>
                    
                </LinearLayout>    
                    
            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

        </ViewSwitcher>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Apply this layout XML and Let me know if anything Required more.

Answer (score 0):

the problem simply is you are using scrolling view inside scrolling view so
I suggest you to make text scrollable in another way like making it read only edit text `android:editable="false"` or `Edittext.setEnabled(false);`  and play with colors

or

give enough space to text view

or

adjust text size

or you can give focus when you tab on scrolling view like

Comment: the edittext trick could works but I'd like a solid solution with textview, I can't believe there is not a way to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
 ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(listRecyclerView, false);
```

You might try this to fix the scrolling problem.

Comment: listrecyclerview what is?

Comment: your recyclerView.

Comment: I don't use recycler view there, It's a bottom sheet dialog with just 2 nestedscrollview inside